# How to print minimum of numbers in c++ with for loop?

Tags: c++

I wrote this piece of code, which has `t` test cases, and for every test cases it would input 3 digits. I want this program to then identify the minimum element among those three inputs, and then print the minimum element. What should I do?

```cpp
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       {
           int n;
           cin>>n;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you get the inputs, compare the current one with the previous one and keep the minimum value.

Comment: IMHO, you should read the digits as `char`.  You can still determine the minimum of the three.

Comment: so if we input 10,2,3 then 2 must be printed right?

Comment: @RohithV yes but i figured it out. i needed to do like this if there are three variables a,b,c then minimum=min(a,min(b,c)). and then cout<<minimum;

Comment: I provided an answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a example of finding the minimum of three digits, using a running minimum:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int test_case_quantity = 0U;
    std::cin >> test_case_quantity;
    while(test_case_quantity--)
    {
        char minimum;
        std::cin >> minimum;
        char digit;
        std::cin >> digit;
        if (digit < minimum) minimum = digit;
        std::cin >> digit;
        if (digit < minimum) minimum = digit;
        std::cout << "    minimum: " << minimum << "\n";
        std::cin.ignore(100000, '\n'); // Synchronize to next line.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For a more robust program, you can add validation that the character read is actually numeric.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the benefit of reading a `char` as opposed to an `int`? As you mentioned, doing so can have consequences, in particular when a user enters a non-numeric number. So why use a `char` if it complicates the solution?

Comment: When reading as a number, you have to isolate the digits by division and remainder.  Division and remainder take up a lot of execution time.  Besides, the `char` type **is a** numeric data type and the `operator<` can be applied to them.

Comment: Ah I see. It's a bit of a runtime optimization. Since the lexicographical ordering of numeric characters is the same as their integer counterparts, the "find minimum" logic works the same.

Comment: Then doesn't this solution only work with single digit inputs? I apologize for continuing the conversation but if so I think it is useful to state this limitation.

Comment: As I stated, this is for the minimum of 3 digits, not 3 numbers.  I got the idea from the OP's question:  *for every test cases it would input 3 digits*.  If you want numbers, that's a different implementation..

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of an extra variable say `small` and when we are inputting the very first number, we can assign that first number to the `small` and in all other cases we can compare whether the current number is less than `small`, if yes then update `small`.
Finally outside the loop we can print the value of small and this will be our answer.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int small;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            int n;
            cin>>n;
            if (i == 0)
                small = n;
            else {
                if (n < small)
                    small = n;
            }
        }
        cout<<"Smallest number is :" << small;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input :

```
1
10 2 3
```

output :

```
Smallest number is :2
```

Flow :
At first the value 10 will be assigned as small, then for the next element 2, we compare whether 2 is less than small which is 10 in that case, and reassign small to 2. Then this small is checked with 3, but 2 < 3, so small value remains unchanged.

I assume there will be only integer values as input.

Comment: This is the right idea, and the next logical enhancement to the OP's code without complicating the solution. For a runtime optimization, and modern C++ style, look to Thomas Matthew's answer.

Comment: This violates the OP's request of *for every test cases it would input 3 digits*.  The numbers presented for input don't contain 3 digits.  At least that's my understanding.